# Restrict text file deletion

Tags: c#

Can anybody tell me how can I restrict a file deletion.

I could achieve it by denying the file permissions for deleting a file using delete button, however file is getting deleted on click of shift + delete button.

Thank you

Comment: Where are you planning to delete from? From within C# Code or from Windows Explorer commands too?

Comment: This looks more like a question about file system and operating system (and thus off-topic here). Unless you specify more precisely how this is related to C# (by giving the code attempt you made that didn't work, for instance).

Comment: I delete from Windows explorer.